# parse push recipient limit

Tags: parse-platform, notifications, push-notification

i want to use parse push notification for my application. but i have some questions:

1- what is the maximum number of notifications for a month? In parse.com, they say "1.000.000 unique recipient is free". Are there any limits like that :"you cans send maximum 10.000.000 notifications in a month"?

2- what is the maximum number of recipients for one parse push notification request (from parse.com or from parse REST API)? are there any limits for a notification like that : "you can send a notification up to XXX users with one request"? for example my application is downloaded by 100k users. can i send a notification to all that 100k users with one request? And are all the notifications sent to all users at the same time?

3- i send a notification to 5K users with one API request. Does it count as one request or more? If i use query, for example "send a notification to users which have a car and an iphone" , does it count as one request or more?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the basic free plan from parse, you can send a push notification to 1.000.000 unique identifiers at the same time. Please have a look at [this](https://www.parse.com/plans) link.
But note that the pushes are likely to not arrive at the same time exactly, they can be a few seconds apart, esp. for such large numbers.

Second, yes, this counts as one API request as you effectively make one call to their servers. However, if you make some queries before sending the push (separate queries, no complex queries that are made with the push request), they would also count as a separate API request.

**EDIT:**
In case you are querying the users to send a notification to per code, you are likely to be bound to the general limit of 1.000 results per `PFQuery`.

Comment: i could not understand:"However, if you make some queries before sending the push (separate queries, no complex queries that are made with the push request), they would also count as a separate API request."

Comment: Maybe a bit weird that sentence, I agree lol. It's simple, if you need to make some queries before you can actually send the push, those will count as separate API request, that's quite trivial. However, complex queries where you effectively only make one server call only count as one single API request. It's basically dead simple, every time you call their servers, it counts as an API request.

Comment: i want to send a notification like that :
  -d '{
        "where": {
          "deviceType": "ios" ,"haveCar" :"true", "haveIphone" :"true"
        },
        "data": {
          "alert": "You have one car and one iphone!"
        }
      }' \
  is it a separate query or not? is it 1 request or more? and according to your edit, can i send it more than 1000 users, for example 100k users?

Comment: @EricSchanet I don't think it would be separate API calls for query. Just using queries and send firing the notification should count as 1 API call if the results are not fetched from Parse on the client side

Comment: @AkshayChordiya exactly what I meant to say. The query that is needed for the push notification counts as 1 API call (together with the push). However, there can be cases where you need to do other queries (with actually fetching data) before doing the notification.

Answer (score 0):

This how Parse explains unique recipients.

> How does Parse define 'unique recipients' for push notification pricing?
>   'Unique recipients' is the number of distinct devices a push notification is sent to in a given month. If a particular device receives multiple push notifications in a month, that only counts as one 'unique recipient'. If a particular user owns multiple devices, and a push notification is sent to each of these devices, that will count as multiple 'unique recipients'.